# window.location alternatives in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, redirect

What is a standardized alternative to `window.location.href` property? I was checking on w3schools.com that it is implemented in all major browsers so there's no problem but I'm rather curious how to do that properly.

From here is the statement that the function is not standardized: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location

Thanks!

Comment: `href` is a property and not a method of the `location` object. And you will have no issues using it .. (*standard would be to use links instead of javascript to navigate in a site ;)*)

Comment: fixed :-) I was rewriting my question..

Comment: document.URL returns a string that is the url of the current document, which may not be the location.href value, if the page was redirected.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `window` object goes back as far as the original JavaScript implementation in Netscape 2.0, and `location` has existed in every browser since then.

The Browser Object Model outside of the DOM has tradionally not been standardised, but that changes with HTML5, which documents [the `window` object](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-window-object) and [its `location` property](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#dom-location) explicitly.

Answer (score 8):

There is nothing wrong with setting `window.location`.

Answer (score 1):

There's no standardized way of doing it. The most well-supported way of redirecting the browser is using the `href` property of the `location` object:

```
window.location.href = "http://www.google.com/";
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `location.href` is having a collateral effect on WordPress dashboard.
If I add buttons that use `location.href` for navigation, it prompts an alert pop up asking if I want to leave the page without saving.

Using [**`location.replace`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/replace) works great though. It's description explains its difference to the other alternative, [**`assign()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/assign):

> The replace() method of the Location interface replaces the current resource with the one at the provided URL. The difference from the `assign()` method is that after using replace() the current page will not be saved in session History, meaning the user won't be able to use the back button to navigate to it.