# How to redirect without using window.location

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html, redirect

If I click a button from page A, the browser will redirect to page B. In page B if I click a another button again it redirects to Page A. Here I used `window.location.href` to redirect the new page.

eg:`window.location.href="http:\\localhost:12345\index2.html"`

Is any other alternative way to redirect next page. I don't want to use `windows.location`

**Update:**

If I use `windows.location` the url which I come from is stored in  `document.reffer`. For security purposes I don't want to allow to store the url.

Comment: Why don't you want to use ```window.location```? It's the standard way to redirect using JavaScript

Comment: There already is an equal question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958203/window-location-alternatives-in-javascript

Comment: You can add links - <a> tags - and style with CSS them to look like buttons...but I have the same question as @Sean - why no window.location?

Comment: if i use 'window.location' document.reffer is holding my previous page's url. i want to avoid this

Comment: Agreed with @motanelu suggestion. Checkout this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/710089/how-do-i-make-an-html-link-look-like-a-button).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-do-i-redirect-to-another-page-in-javascript-jquery

Comment: Why keep people guessing....what is the actual problem you have?

Comment: Try this : [Stack overflow question on clearing the referer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6817595/remove-http-referer)

Comment: @freedomn-m updated

Comment: Loading a new page via `window.location` does not allow you to add custom headers.

Answer (score 6):

### Location assign() Method

You may use this method 
example :-

```js
function myFunction() {
    location.assign("https://www.google.co.in");
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Load new document</button>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also use

```
window.location.replace("http://someUrl.com");
```

replace() does not keep the originating page in the session history.

Answer (score 1):

Using `$location` in angularjs : See the documentation https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location

Comment: OP hasn't mentioned anything about using Angular...?

Comment: So, why the tag "angularjs" is here ?

Comment: Sorry my bad, didn't notice

Answer (score 0):

```
$url =$('<a/>')
$url.attr('href',"http://google.com");
$url[0].click()
```

You can try this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **location.assign()** for redirect another page.

```
location.assign("https://www.facebook.com/");
```

Comment: Keep in mind that `location.assign` is subject to same-origin-policy and will throw a security exception if the page is not from the same  location. See [MDN Web API Reference - window.location.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/assign).

Answer (score -1):

why not use `<a>`. what you only to do is give it a class like button.